# NN: Predicting choices when number of alternatives changes

Tags: neural-networks

Let's say I want to model purchase data (i.e. purchase records of many households across time). For simplicity, let's assume each household only picks one alternative at the time. A simple starting point is a multinomial logit model. Then, more flexible network architectures could be used. People have applied NN to this, but kept the number of alternatives (K) constant. In reality, the number of available options changes over time. Also, it would be interesting to predict how choices change when the number of alternatives is changed.

in bullet points

- there are N households
- t_n purchases for each household
- There are K_t alternatives at time t
- Dependent variable Y=k indicates that alternative k was bought
- Each alternative is characterized by features, so x_kt is a vector of those features (including brand name, price, ...). The number of features is constant across time.

Any guidance or ideas?